# Does setUp method from unittest.TestCase know the current test case?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Does the setUp method from the unittest.TestCase knows what is the next test case that will be executed? For example:

```
import unittest

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "The next test will be: " + self.next_test_name()

    def test_01(self):
        pass

    def test_02(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Such code should produce upon execution:

```
The next test will be: test_01
The next test will be: test_02
```

Comment: Did you try? Does it work?

Comment: "has no attribute next_test_name"

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "The next test will be: " + self.id()

    def test_01(self):
        pass

    def test_02(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Which will produce:

```
The next test will be: __main__.Tests.test_01
The next test will be: __main__.Tests.test_02
```

Answer (score 4):

No, `unittest` makes no guarantee about the order of test execution.

Moreover, you should structure your unit tests not to rely on any particular order.  If they require some state setup from another test method then you no longer have, by definition, a *unit* test.

The **current** test method name which will be executed lives in `self._testMethodName`, but use it at your own risk (accessing `_private` attributes is subject to breakage without warning).  Do not use this to customise `setUp` based on the particular test method, prefer to split tests requiring a different setup off into separate test classes.

Comment: I do not want to know the particular order. I only want to know what will be the next test case that will be executed

Comment: You might be able to get at it with a `nose` plugin.  But why do you want to know it?  This sounds like an XY problem ..

Comment: To have difiirent setUp for specific test cases

Comment: Then put them in different test classes

Comment: note, if you open to using a different test runner `py.test` does allow you to customise the setup for particular methods